# Past tense short な-adjective + ので

Tags: grammar

From what I know, ので differs to から grammatically because you add a な after な-adjectives for ので. For example:

> その人は意地悪{いじわる}なので、嫌{きら}いです。- I do not like that person because they are mean.

But what would the past tense of this sentence be? Would it be:

> その人は意地悪{いじわる}だった**な**ので、嫌{きら}いです。- I do not like that person because they WERE mean.

Is the な before ので necessary for past tense adjectives? I couldn't really find anything after googling. How does this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

な is the attributive form of the copula だ (plain form of です). It is what だ becomes when that part of the sentence moves from the predicative position to form a relative clause (sometimes called an adjective clause because it functions like an adjective):

> - 部屋がきれいだ - The room is clean
> - きれいな部屋 - A clean room

---

There is no requirement for だ→な for sentences ending in verbs (not ending in だ) for the verb to form a relative clause. **There is no need to insert a な here because だ was not there to become な.** Inserting な would be grammatically wrong. The predicative form and the attributive form looks the same for verbs:

> - この手紙はペンで書いた - This letter was written by a pen
> - ペンで書いた手紙 - A pen-written letter

---

The past tense (or perfective aspect) of だ is だった. Even though だ→な when changing from predicative to attributive, だった remains as だった. **There is no need to insert a な here either**. Inserting な here would be grammatically wrong:

> - 部屋が静かだった - The room was quiet
> - 静かだった部屋 - The room that was quiet

---

What precedes ので has to end in attributive form:

> - Verb: するので
> - Verb(past): したので
> - i-adj: 高いので
> - i-adj(past): 高かったので
> - na-adj: 静かなので
> - na-adj(past): 静かだったので
> - noun: 学生なので
> - noun(past): 学生だったので

---

So finally in your sentence:

> その人は意地悪だった**な**ので、嫌いです。 (☓)

There is no need to insert **な** there since だった is already the correct form.

Comment: +1, but when you say "there is no need to ..."  it admits the possibility that adding な might be permissible even if it is not needed. I think it would be safer to make clear that, not only is it not needed, it is not grammatical.

Comment: @user3856370 I can see how it might mean that. I wouldn't say that it admits that possibility. I'd say it does not preclude that possibility.

Comment: I thought those two meanings were the same. Anyway, I'm not going to quibble over English in a Japanese language site :-)